# Multiple addEventListeners triggered on the "change" event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onchange, addeventlistener

I have a select box that's used to navigate to a new page on the "change" event and record some analytics. I want two event handlers to fire so that both of the handlers trigger on "change" rather than just the last function assigned to onchange.  I just need to know what I need to put in the function() with the // Placeholder text so that both events are triggered on the "change" event. I want the answer to be plain ole JavaScript not jQuery.  Thank you :)  Here's the code:

Javascript

Treehouse Challenge:
"We've got a select box that's used to navigate to a new page on the "change" event and record some analytics. We want two event handlers to fire, fix lines 14 and 15 so that both of the handlers trigger on "change" rather than just the last function assigned to onchange."

```
//Select select box
var navigationSelect = document.getElementById("nav");

//Navigate to URL when select box is changed
var navigateToValue = function() {
  window.location = this.value;
}

//Send analytics data
var sendAnalytics = function() {
  //Placeholder  
}

navigationSelect.onchange = navigateToValue;
navigationSelect.onchange = sendAnalytics;
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <select id="nav">
            <option value="index.html">Home</option>
            <option value="about.html">About</option>
        </select>

        <h1>About</h1>

        <script src="app.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jason, could you tell us what you've already tried to put in the `sendAnalytics` function, and why that isn't working?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to fill in the placeholder. The challenge says just to fix lines 14 and 15.

Comment: Yep :) You are 100% correct.  Got it to work once I left the placeholder code alone.  lol

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this via:

```
document.getElementById('nav').addEventListener('change', function(){
  sendAnalytics();
  navigateToValue();
}
```

Or

```
navigationSelect.addEventListener('change', sendAnalytics, false);
navigationSelect.addEventListener('change', navigateTo, false);
```

**addEventListener** in this case is responsible for assigning a 'change' event listener onto your nav select element.  Once the event has been detected you call your additional functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I can't get that to work.  I need to know what goes inside the sendAnalytics function

Comment: Can you please clarify more about what you are intending to put inside the sendAnalytics function?  What have you tried?

Comment: This is what I have tried: 
var navigationSelect = document.getElementById("nav");

//Navigate to URL when select box is changed
var navigateToValue = function() {
  window.location = this.value;
}

//Send analytics data
var sendAnalytics = function() {
  navigationSelect.onchange = navigateToValue;
  navigationSelect.onchange = sendAnalytics;
}

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish with your sendAnalystics function?  Right now it is just an empty function, you have not provided any details regarding what you want this function to do, so we are unable to help you?

Comment: I updated the code above with what I have tried.  The sendAnalytics function is just a function that navigates to a new page on the "change" event and store the changes made

Comment: What changes are you trying to store?

Comment: OK, confession time:  This code snippet is for a code challenge on Team Treehouse that is about plain ole JavaScript.  Here is what the challenge is:                                                    "We've got a select box that's used to navigate to a new page on the "change" event and record some analytics. We want two event handlers to fire, fix lines 14 and 15 so that both of the handlers trigger on "change" rather than just the last function assigned to onchange."

Comment: Of course, you should up-vote some of the answers users provided that you found helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have something like this?

```
document.getElementById('nav').addEventListener('change', function(){
  navigateToValue();

}

function navigateToValue(){
  window.location = this.value();

//you know the data going into sendAnalytics at this point

    sendAnalystics();
}

function sendAnalytics(){
  //your function body
}
```

Comment: OK, confession time:  This code snippet is for a code challenge on Team Treehouse that is about plain ole JavaScript.  Here is what the challenge is:                                                    "We've got a select box that's used to navigate to a new page on the "change" event and record some analytics. We want two event handlers to fire, fix lines 14 and 15 so that both of the handlers trigger on "change" rather than just the last function assigned to onchange."  I edited the code above to show what the challenge says and the code they gave me to work with.

Comment: Well in that case I would have something like this. Im not really sure if that is the right way to go about it.

`$.when(navigateToValue()).done(sendAnalystics())`

Comment: I'm sure that would work but it can't be jQuery, has to be plain ole vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: `document.getElementById('nav').addEventListener('change', function(){
  navigateToValue();sendAnalytics();
}`

Did you try this as line 14 and 15? Is it throwing any error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach in the current answers, or one of the following. Assign to the property per the current code:

```
var sendAnalytics = function() {
    navigationSelect.onchange = function() {
      sendAnalytics();
      navigateToValue();
    } 
};
```

which creates a single listener that calls the functions in sequence. If you require *this* within the functions to be the element on which the listeners are placed, then:

```
var sendAnalytics = function() {
    navigationSelect.onchange = function() {
      sendAnalytics.call(navigationSelect);
      navigateToValue.call(navigationSelect);
    } 
};
```

Note that you should send the analytics first as once you initiate navigation, script execution may halt immediately and *sendAnalytics* may not be called.

Multiple calls to addEventListener:

```
var sendAnalytics = function() {
    navigationSelect.addEventListener('change', sendAnalytics, false); 
    navigationSelect.addEventListener('change', navigateToValue, false);
};
```

which creates two listeners for the same event and sets *this* as expected. However, the order of execution of the listeners is not guaranteed.

Note that in some browsers (e.g. IE) when navigating a select's options, a change event is fired each time the keys are used to navigate to the next option. If the *change* event triggers navigation, users will not get past the first option.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks awesome.  However...Treehouse is kind of picky and none of these options work.  I get the error   "Bummer! You haven't added any `'change'` event handlers with the `addEventListener()` method."

Comment: Try just changing lines 14 and 15 to the second method in my answer, which is the same as the body of the last method @RobG provided

Comment: So why should the fact that Treehouse can't properly analyse the code be **our** problem? ;-) As you can see from the range of answers, there are lots of ways to overcome the issue and it doesn't necessarily require the use of *addEventListener*.

Answer (score 0):

the code that the Treehouse Challenge is looking for on line 14 and 15 is:

```
navigationSelect.addEventListener ("change", navigateToValue);
navigationSelect.addEventListener ("change", sendAnalytics);
```